# how to get the count of the NSArray inside of another NSArray?

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` containing multiple `NSArray`s. But I need get the `count` or size of a particular array but I can not figureout how to do it.

I try in the console:

> p [_mainArray[0]count] // error: no known method '-count'; cast the message send to the method's return type

I'll really appreciate if any of knows how can I get the count of the array inside of the array.

Comment: that's definitely wrong

Comment: @rmaddy I see now how that was wrong. I removed the confusion. Thank you for pointing out the misconception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error suggests, you need to cast the object that you retrieve from the array:

```
p [(NSArray *)_mainArray[0] count]
```

Comment: I think it actually wants `p (int)[ _mainArray[0] count ]`, no?

Comment: @nielsbot Hmmm. Now I'm not sure.

Comment: no the person who wrote this was correct, an int cast wouldn't make a difference

Comment: Either works. `p (int)[someArray[0] count]` works just fine. (Technically, it should be NSUInteger).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `_mainArray[0]` returns a type of `id`. To help the debugger, do what it says:

```
p [(NSArray *)_mainArray[0] count];
```

The cast tells the debugger that the results of `_mainArray[0]` is an `NSArray`.

Comment: I think it actually wants `p (int)[ _mainArray[0] count ]`, no?

Comment: no the person who wrote this was correct, an int cast wouldn't make a difference

Comment: the problem is not the the result is not properly cast, it is that _mainArray[0] has no given type and thus cannot call any methods